# vector, removing object trouble

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, stdvector, erase

I am new to c++ and am currently learning sfml.

I have set up a system that adds one 'Snowpile' object to the vector. But when I keep hitting errors like "can't increment vector past iterator past end" or that it's outside the scope.

```
std::vector<Snowpile*> snowpiles;
```

I want it to check every snowpile for the removed2 bool, and delete the ones that do have it.

```
for (auto s_it = snowpiles.begin(); s_it != snowpiles.end(); s_it++) {
    int sindex = std::distance(snowpiles.begin(), s_it);
    if (snowpiles[sindex]->getSprite_S().getGlobalBounds().intersects(player.getSpriteP().getGlobalBounds()) && snowpiles[sindex]->melting == false) {
        snowpiles[sindex]->melting = true;
    }
    else if (snowpiles[sindex]->getSprite_S().getGlobalBounds().intersects(player.getSpriteP().getGlobalBounds()) && snowpiles[sindex]->melting == true) {
        snowpiles[sindex]->melting = true;
    }
    else if (!snowpiles[sindex]->getSprite_S().getGlobalBounds().intersects(player.getSpriteP().getGlobalBounds()) && snowpiles[sindex]->melting == true) {
        snowpiles[sindex]->melting = false;
    }
    snowpiles[sindex]->meltedrem(sindex, snowpiles, m_win);
    if (snowpiles[sindex]->removed2 == true)
    {
        cout << "Detected removed 2 at " << sindex << endl;
        //delete snowpiles[sindex];
        snowpiles.erase(snowpiles.begin() + sindex - 1);
    }
        

}
```

The melting parts determine whether the player is on top of a snowpile. The meltdrem functions checks for bool 'melting' == true and then proceeds to start the timer. After a few seconds (+ animations) it sets the bool removed2 to true.

I know that at the program at least sees the bools changing, so thats not it.

Am I simply using vector wrong, or do I need to change something in my loop?
The loop is located in the while(window.isOpen()) loop in int main.

Comment: `snowpiles.erase(snowpiles.begin() + sindex - 1);` invalidates the iterator `s_it`. You should iterate with indexes and just don't increment it, when you remove an element.

Comment: *I have set up a system that adds one 'Snowpile' object to the vector* -- You didn't do that.  You added a `Snowpile` *pointer*, not an object.  That is a big difference.

Comment: Off-topic, but I bet that all of that multiline logic could be simplified into a `std::vector::erase(std::remove_if)` combination.  That would remove the need to call `erase` multiple times, thus invalidating iterators.

Answer (score 1):

For starters it is unclear why there is used the expression

```
snowpiles.erase(snowpiles.begin() + sindex - 1);
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

instead of

```
snowpiles.erase(snowpiles.begin() + sindex);
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

if in a comment you wrote

```
//delete snowpiles[sindex];
```

You need to increase the iterator in the for loop only when a current object was not removed.

Change the loop the following way

```
for (auto s_it = snowpiles.begin(); s_it != snowpiles.end(); ) {
    //...
    if (snowpiles[sindex]->removed2 == true)
    {
        cout << "Detected removed 2 at " << sindex << endl;
        //delete snowpiles[sindex];
        s_it = snowpiles.erase( s_it );
    }
    else
    {
        ++s_it;
    }
}
```